# I can not install Angular-cli in windows 10

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm doing a course to learn Angular,
I've been trying to install angular-cli for 2 days, I've tried various solutions that I read about, but I always get the same mistakes.

I'm on windows 10, node -v 6.9.1, npm -v 3.10.8

[image]

After reading, I said to change the version of node from 8 to 6. After installation I went to see the folder located in C: \ Users \ Aurora \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm and that'sis empty, is there any mistake?

Thanks for your answers guys.

Initially I had installed the latest version of node, but in the forum of the course I'm following have suggested to upgrade to version 6.9.1 to not have problems with the installation of angular-cli.

So I uninstalled the node, deleted the related folders and reinstalled everything, I tried again but nothing has changed.

The folder located in C: \ Users \ Aurora \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm was empty, now I installed node_modules, typing in the cmd "npm install -g npm" and inserted in the system variable path "C: \ Users \ Aurora \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm ".

I just tried again and it seems that angular-cli has been installed, it gives me these 3 errors:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running powershell as admin?

Comment: There is a line `Make sure you have the latest version`. Have you tried the latest version of node and npm?

Comment: @AuroraRuggieri, those are warnings only, and these particular warnings can be safely ingnored.